# when I build a PyObject with C API of Python3, its ob_type is NULL

Tags: python, python-3.x, c++11, python-c-api

I ran such code in C++11:

```
PyObject* aa = PyLong_FromLong(7L);
```

Then I checked the value of `aa`, it's not `NULL`, but `aa->ob_type` was `NULL`.

However, when I ran:

```
PyObject* aa = PyLong_FromLong(257L);
```

`aa->ob_type` was **not** `NULL` anymore. I read the document of PyLong_FromLong, and found this:

```
PyObject* PyLong_FromLong(long v)
Return value: New reference. 
Return a new PyLongObject object from v, or NULL on failure.

The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour of Python in this case is undefined. :-)
```

Seems that when building `PyLongObject` between -5 and 256 will meet this problem. But I don't understand the reason.

What's more, this problem doesn't appear in Python2. That's incredible!

Comment: Related: [“is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: In Python2 there's two integer types. `PyInt` is the smaller type, so I think -5 -> 256 will be defined there and not for `PyLong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized Python. Since these small objects are special-cased they are set up when Python is initialized.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyObject* aa = PyLong_FromLong(7L);
  printf("aa=%d\naa->ob_type=%p\n",PyLong_AsLong(aa),aa->ob_type);
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

correctly prints

> `aa=7`
>
> `aa->ob_type=0x7f380d6b5800` (note that this will vary from run to run)

If I comment out `Py_Initialize()` and `Py_Finalize()` then I get a segmentation fault, but if I don't try reading the value with `PyLong_AsLong` then I get a null pointer for `ob_type`.

---

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding) does tell you to initialize the interpreter.

---

With respect to Python2 it has two integer types `PyInt` and `PyLong` with `PyInt` handling the small values and so having the special-cased table. You'll probably see the same issue if you use `PyInt` in Python2. Anything you do with Python before calling `Py_Initialize` is undefined though, so it could fail in different exciting ways.